# What are standard rgb colors for SWT progress Bar

Tags: java, swt, progress-bar

What are standard rgb colors for eclipse SWT progress Bar for every state:

```
SWT.NORMAL
SWT.ERROR
SWT.PAUSED
```

Unfortunately, I can not find it anywhere and I don't want to use color picker from paint or Photoshop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The progress bar is drawn by a native control and looks substantially different (and has different colors) on each platform. So there isn't a simple way to get these colors.